# How can I use a local variable outside of a Async Task method?

Tags: c#, async-await

How can I assign "ip" outside of this method? This is my fist time asking a question on here.

```
public async Task GetIPAsync()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    string response = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("https://www.meethue.com/api/nupnp"));
    string ip = JArray.Parse(response).First["internalipaddress"].ToString();        
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "assign outside of the method"?  Do you just want `ip` to be a class-level variable?  Something else?

Comment: Replace `async Task` by `async Task<string>` and add `return ip;` at the end of your method.

Comment: Yes, I want ip to be a class level variable. Thanks for the fast response.

Answer (score 5):

```
public async Task<string> GetIPAsync()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    string response = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("https://www.meethue.com/api/nupnp"));
    string ip = JArray.Parse(response).First["internalipaddress"].ToString();
    return ip;
}

// Then to call it, do:
string ip = await GetIPAsync();
```

Comment: When I call it, it wants to make my other methods  async Task<IActionResult> Methodname() , I just want to be able to use "ip" class wide. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Then call it through: `string ip = GetIPAsync().Result;` . Note that you loose the advantage of it being async, but that's not really an issue.

Comment: @JohanBoulé depending on the context `GetIPAsync().Result` is a bad idea, because it might result in a deadlock! See here for further details: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment above:

> I want ip to be a class level variable

Then make it a class-level variable.  For example:

```
private string ip;

public async Task GetIPAsync()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    string response = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("https://www.meethue.com/api/nupnp"));
    ip = JArray.Parse(response).First["internalipaddress"].ToString();        
}
```

This would increase the scope of the `ip` variable to be available to other instance methods in that class.

(Note of course that the state of this class-level variable is going to be tied to the sequence of events in your asynchronous operations.  Which is at this time a bit outside the scope of what you're demonstrating in the question.)

(Also note that this approach may be a bit less intuitive than simple returning the value, [which was answered elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45653051/328193) on this question.  A "GetSomething" method is something that I'd expect to return a value.  Also, by returning the value, you have more control over the scope of that value and the re-use safety of the method.  If you *want* the value to be class-level, this is how you'd do it.  But that might not be the best approach for what you're actually building.)

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work for me. When I pass it to the ViewBag it does not display it.

Comment: @user8112613: There's nothing in the question about a ViewBag or anything related to that.  If something else isn't working somewhere else in your code, that sounds like material for a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: I mentioned the ViewBag as an example of how i want to use "ip". I can't seem to be able to use ip out side of the method.

Comment: @user8112613: If you can actually demonstrate and describe the problem, we may be able to help.  "It doesn't work" doesn't really describe anything.  Again, there is *no* mention of `ViewBag` or anything related to that in your question.  If something isn't working *somewhere else in your code* unrelated to what is being shown in the question, then clearly you have made a mistake somewhere.  But nobody here can know what that is without seeing any information about it.

Comment: Ok, So the GetIPAsync() gets the IP of my Phillips Hue bridge, and I want to be able to display that IP to the ViewBag. Maybe I am  not asking the right questions, my apologies I am new to C#

Comment: @user8112613: So how are you using the value?  Are you sure it successfully got the value?  If the method is getting the value, why don't you just have the method *return* the value instead of set a class-level variable?  (The other answer posted before mine.)

Comment: ip does get the value, i want to use ip in this manner public IActionResult Index()
        {

            
            ViewBag.IP = ip;

            return View();

        }

Comment: @user8112613: That example never calls the `GetIPAsync()` method.  That method is what *sets* the value.  You can't use a value that you never set in the first place.